# How can I clear or erase all allocations from kmem_cache in a kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm developing a module in kernel that uses kmem_cache. While developing and testing, it's possible that something goes wrong or I want to quit the module while there are still some allocations from the cache that weren't freed.
Calling `kmem_cache_destroy` with a cache that still has elements throws a protection fault in dmesg: `kmem_cache_destroy <my_cache>: Slab cache still has objects` along with the usual huge dump.

Is it possible to somehow remove all elements from a kmem_cache to avoid this issue?

Something like this reproduces the issue:

```
#include <linux/slab.h>

static struct kmem_cache *cache;
cache = kmem_cache_create("my_cache", 8, 4, 0, null_constructor);
c = kmem_cache_alloc(cmd_cache, GFP_KERNEL);
c1 = kmem_cache_alloc(cmd_cache, GFP_KERNEL);
//TODO: free all elements of the cache, without referencing every single object allocated
kmem_cache_destroy(cache);
```

Comment: void kmem_cache_free(kmem_cache_t *cache, const void *obj);   https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch08.html

Comment: I copied the wrong line into the code. Fixed now since I am using `kmem_cache_alloc`.

Comment: Note: I'm not sure but you probably want to use `kmem_cache_alloc_bulk` to allocate your objects and then `kmem_cache_free_bulk` once you're done. Or simply create an array to hold the objects you alloc and then loop over it and free each one. Just like you'd do with any other data type.

Comment: I was already storing the objects in an xarray, so I ended up iterating over it, freeing every entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate each object with

```
void *kmem_cache_alloc(kmem_cache_t *cache, int flags);
```

then free all objects

```
void kmem_cache_free(kmem_cache_t *cache, const void *obj);
```

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596005903/ch08.html

Comment: I *should* use kmem_cache_free on every element added, sure. The question is, is it possible to free all elements of the cache without having a reference to them, like a clear() function.

Comment: I guess there is no such function. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/memory-allocation.html

Comment: Check  kmem_cache_free_bulk
 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/slab.c#L3740